# How to add custom hosts to apache on windows

Tags: windows, apache, localhost

I wanna know how add two projects on `zf2` in htdocs. 
I have in `my /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.config` this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/test1
ServerName test1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/test2
ServerName test2
</VirtualHost>
```

and in my hosts file i have:

```
127.0.0.1 test1.com
127.0.0.1 test2.com
```

Tanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

*You should really work on the quality of your question. You used completely wrong tags, this question is not at all related to `zend-framework2` and `projects`. I removed those tags and added some other more relevant ones. I assumed you are using `apache` on `windows`. If wrong please change it according to your specs. I also changed the title so people with similar issues can actually find your question.*

To answer your question:

I would suggest leaving the `.com` away and then do it like this:

```
<VirtualHost test1:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/test1
    ServerName test1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost test2:80>
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/test2
    ServerName test2
</VirtualHost>
```

so **domain_name:80**
and then in your hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 test1
127.0.0.1 test2
```

Comment: Tanks for reply, i will repost my answer:  i have two projects on zend framework 2 in /lampp/htdocs, why can i do for run in the same time.

Comment: @EstebanVilla to run both do as I wrote in the answer